# internal-sftp on chroot jail disconnects with status 1?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, chroot

Server: `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`

SSHD: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n`

I have created a test user `sftpuser` and `sftp` group to try logging in through a WinSCP client, as a start. In `sshd_config` I have the following block at the end:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO    
Match group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u/www
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

A further example of my permissions in /home/sftpuser:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root 4096 Nov  2 08:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root 4096 Nov  2 08:27 ../
drwx------ 2 sftpuser sftp 4096 Nov  2 08:33 .ssh/
drwx------ 2 root     root 4096 Nov  2 08:47 www/
```

No matter the permissions/ownership (i.e. root:sftp, sftpuser:sftp, etc.) when it seems correctly set up the debug logs seem to say nothing, and WinSCP client says 'server has sent exit status 1' with no further information.

auth.log (with DEBUG level logging)

```
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: debug1: matching key found: file /home/sftpuser/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA [snip]
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: Accepted publickey for sftpuser from [snip] port 60326 ssh2: RSA [snip]
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: sftpuser has been authenticated by privileged process
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24104]: User child is on pid 24106
Nov  2 20:24:07 srv sshd[24106]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
Nov  2 20:24:26 srv sshd[23869]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request window-change reply 0
Nov  2 20:24:26 srv sshd[23869]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Nov  2 20:24:26 srv sshd[23869]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req window-change
```

How can I even begin to find out what is happening to internal-sftp? I tried the default uncommented sftp-server as well, to no avail.

Comment: I forgot to mention, just in case, sftp user is: ` sftpuser:x:1001:1002::/home/sftpuser:/sbin/nologin `